# Typo in _admin/metrics

Tags: arangodb, telegraf

I've started setting up different tools on my home server to create apps for personal use and experience. I'm using telegraf to pull metrics from arangodb's _admin/metrics but getting an error. This is due to one line in the response has a typo which has "guage" instead of "gauge".

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/administration-and-monitoring.html#RestAdminMetrics_container
#TYPE arangodb_client_connection_statistics_client_connections guage

Will this be fixed in the next update? Also, if there is any workaround for now, please share. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in PR https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/10625 which will be part of v3.7. I don't know if this will also be backported to 3.6, so you might want to create an issue on github.